# GPS Speedometer value didnt come out

Tags: arduino-uno, gps, speed

I'm building a GPS speedometer. I use Neo-6M module for GPS, Arduino uno and 128x64 OLED screen for monitoring the value. I've checked the GPS module. It gives me data about latitude and longitude. But on the OLED screen it didnt come out value. I NEED HELP. this is the code.

```
    /*
  Connections:
  GPS TX -> Arduino 0 // Disconnect Arduino 0 to upload this sketch
  GPS RX -> Arduino 1
  Screen SDA -> Arduino A4
  Screen SCL -> Arduino A5
*/

#include "U8glib.h" // Call U8glib library to control OLED screen

U8GLIB_SSD1306_128X64 u8g(U8G_I2C_OPT_DEV_0|U8G_I2C_OPT_NO_ACK|U8G_I2C_OPT_FAST); // Fast I2C/TWI
static const int RXPin = 3, TXPin = 4;
static const uint32_t GPSBaud = 9600;

#define GPS Serial // Define the serial connection as the GPS module

const unsigned char UBLOX_INIT[] PROGMEM = {
  // These lines of code request data from the satellites. Most are disabled and turned off.
  // Disable NMEA
  0xB5,0x62,0x06,0x01,0x08,0x00,0xF0,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x24, // GxGGA off
  0xB5,0x62,0x06,0x01,0x08,0x00,0xF0,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x01,0x01,0x2B, // GxGLL off
  0xB5,0x62,0x06,0x01,0x08,0x00,0xF0,0x02,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x01,0x02,0x32, // GxGSA off
  0xB5,0x62,0x06,0x01,0x08,0x00,0xF0,0x03,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x01,0x03,0x39, // GxGSV off
  0xB5,0x62,0x06,0x01,0x08,0x00,0xF0,0x04,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x01,0x04,0x40, // GxRMC off
  0xB5,0x62,0x06,0x01,0x08,0x00,0xF0,0x05,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x01,0x05,0x47, // GxVTG off

  // Disable UBX
  0xB5,0x62,0x06,0x01,0x08,0x00,0x01,0x07,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x17,0xDC, // NAV-PVT off
  0xB5,0x62,0x06,0x01,0x08,0x00,0x01,0x02,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x12,0xB9, // NAV-POSLLH off
  0xB5,0x62,0x06,0x01,0x08,0x00,0x01,0x03,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x13,0xC0, // NAV-STATUS off

  // Enable UBX—this is the key information we require
  0xB5,0x62,0x06,0x01,0x08,0x00,0x01,0x07,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x18,0xE1, //NAV-PVT on
  //0xB5,0x62,0x06,0x01,0x08,0x00,0x01,0x02,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x13,0xBE, //NAV-POSLLH on
  //0xB5,0x62,0x06,0x01,0x08,0x00,0x01,0x03,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x14,0xC5, //NAV-STATUS on

  // Rate
  0xB5,0x62,0x06,0x08,0x06,0x00,0x64,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x7A,0x12,    // (10Hz)
  //0xB5,0x62,0x06,0x08,0x06,0x00,0xC8,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x01,0x00,0xDE,0x6A, // (5Hz)
  //0xB5,0x62,0x06,0x08,0x06,0x00,0xE8,0x03,0x01,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x01,0x39  // (1Hz)
};

const unsigned char UBX_HEADER[] = { 0xB5, 0x62 };

struct NAV_PVT { // This sets the GPS navigation data
  unsigned char cls;
  unsigned char id;
  unsigned short len;
  unsigned long iTOW; // GPS time of week of the navigation epoch (ms)

  unsigned short year;     // Year (UTC)
  unsigned char month;     // Month, range 1..12 (UTC)
  unsigned char day;       // Day of month, range 1..31 (UTC)
  unsigned char hour;      // Hour of day, range 0..23 (UTC)
  unsigned char minute;    // Minute of hour, range 0..59 (UTC)
  unsigned char second;    // Seconds of minute, range 0..60 (UTC)
  char valid;              // Validity Flags (see graphic below)
  unsigned long tAcc;      // Time accuracy estimate (UTC) (ns)
  long nano;               // Fraction of second, range -1e9 .. 1e9 (UTC) (ns)
  unsigned char fixType;   // GNSSfix Type, range 0..5
  char flags;              // Fix Status Flags
  unsigned char reserved1; // Reserved
  unsigned char numSV;     // Number of satellites used in Nav Solution

  long lon;           // Longitude (deg)
  long lat;           // Latitude (deg)
  long height;        // Height above Ellipsoid (mm)
  long hMSL;          // Height above mean sea level (mm)
  unsigned long hAcc; // Horizontal Accuracy Estimate (mm)
  unsigned long vAcc; // Vertical Accuracy Estimate (mm)

  long velN;                // NED north velocity (mm/s)
  long velE;                // NED east velocity (mm/s)
  long velD;                // NED down velocity (mm/s)
  long gSpeed;              // Ground Speed (2-D) (mm/s)
  long heading;             // Heading of motion 2-D (deg)
  unsigned long sAcc;       // Speed accuracy estimate
  unsigned long headingAcc; // Heading accuracy estimate
  unsigned short pDOP;      // Position dilution of precision
  short reserved2;          // Reserved
  unsigned long reserved3;  // Reserved
};

NAV_PVT pvt;

void calcChecksum(unsigned char* CK) {
  memset(CK, 0, 2);
for (int i = 0; i < (int)sizeof(NAV_PVT); i++) {
  CK[0] += ((unsigned char*)(&pvt))[i];
  CK[1] += CK[0];
  }
}

long numGPSMessagesReceived = 0;

bool processGPS() {
  static int fpos = 0;
  static unsigned char checksum[2];
  const int payloadSize = sizeof(NAV_PVT);

  while ( GPS.available() ) {
    byte c = GPS.read();
    if ( fpos < 2 ) {
      if ( c == UBX_HEADER[fpos] )
        fpos++;
      else
        fpos = 0;
  }
  else {
    if ( (fpos-2) < payloadSize )
      ((unsigned char*)(&pvt))[fpos-2] = c;

    fpos++;

    if ( fpos == (payloadSize+2) ) {
      calcChecksum(checksum);
    }
    else if ( fpos == (payloadSize+3) ) {
      if ( c != checksum[0] )
         fpos = 0;
    }
    else if ( fpos == (payloadSize+4) ) {
      fpos = 0;
      if ( c == checksum[1] ) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    else if ( fpos > (payloadSize+4) ) {
       fpos = 0;
     }
   }
 }
 return false;
}

void setup() {
  GPS.begin(9600);

  u8g.setColorIndex(1);

 // Send configuration data in UBX protocol
 for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(UBLOX_INIT); i++) {
   GPS.write( pgm_read_byte(UBLOX_INIT+i) );
   delay(5); // Simulate a 38400baud pace (or less),
             // or otherwise commands are not accepted by the device

  }
}

long gSpeed = 0;
int numSV = 0;
unsigned long lastScreenUpdate = 0;
char speedBuf[16];
char satsBuf[16];

char* spinner = "/-\\|"; // Symbol for the spinner on screen to
                         // show communication
byte screenRefreshSpinnerPos = 0;
byte gpsUpdateSpinnerPos = 0;

void loop() {
  if (processGPS()) {
    numSV = pvt.numSV;
    gSpeed = pvt.gSpeed;
    gpsUpdateSpinnerPos = (gpsUpdateSpinnerPos + 1) % 4;
  }

  unsigned long now = millis();
  if (now - lastScreenUpdate > 100) {
     updateScreen();
     lastScreenUpdate = now;
     screenRefreshSpinnerPos = (screenRefreshSpinnerPos + 1) % 4;
  }
}

void draw() {
  u8g.setFont(u8g_font_courB24);
  u8g.drawStr( 36, 45, speedBuf);
  u8g.setFont(u8g_font_fur11);
  u8g.drawStr( 2, 12, satsBuf);
}

void updateScreen() {

  int kmh = gSpeed * 0.0036;
  sprintf(speedBuf, "%3d", kmh);
  sprintf(satsBuf, "%c %c %d", spinner[screenRefreshSpinnerPos], spinner[gpsUpdateSpinnerPos], numSV);

  u8g.firstPage();
  do {
    draw();
  } while( u8g.nextPage() );
}![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Asw5t.jpg)![This is what it shown on my OLED but the value didnt change]
```

Comment: run OLED example code

Comment: What have you tried to debug the code? Can you display literal text? Does the data get correctly read by the Arduino? What is actually happening on the display? (Really nothing, or just not the correct data) Please give us more information

Comment: Instead of tackling two potential problems at once, do it one after the other. 1. Make sure you that you received the position correctly. You may use the serial connection and the IDE's serial monitor for this. 2. Make sure that you can write arbitrary contents on the display.